# Code Coverage to test Custom metadata in Trigger Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-metadata

i have a Trigger class with metadata and i want to make a test class, but i don't know how i do with custom metadata.
The custom metadata is a list that automatically adds member status to each campaign depending on its record type

Who can help me ? I have created a test class but it doesn't work and i know.

TRGHDL_Campaign_Member_Status

```
public with sharing class TRGHDL_Campaign_Member_Status extends TriggerHandler{

    Map<Id, Campaign> mcs = new Map<Id, Campaign>();
    Integer campaignStatusEmailOrder = 0;
    Map<Id, Id> recordTypeIdbyCampaignId = new Map<Id, Id>();
    List <CampaignMemberStatus> lstMemberStatus = new List<CampaignMemberStatus>();
    Id recordTypeEmail;
    Id recordTypeMarketing;

    public override void bulkAfter(Sobject[] newSoList,Map<Id,SObject> oldSoMap){
        recordTypeMarketing = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('AM_Campagnes_evenements_marketing').getRecordTypeId();
        recordTypeEmail = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('AM_Campagne_mass_email').getRecordTypeId();

        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            Set<Id> campaignIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(SObject so : newSoList){
                if (so.get('Id') != null){
                    campaignIds.add((Id)so.get('Id'));
                    recordTypeIdbyCampaignId.put((Id)so.get('Id') , (Id)so.get('RecordTypeID'));

                }
            }
            System.debug(recordTypeIdbyCampaignId);
        }
    }

    public override void afterInsert(SObject so){

        if (recordTypeIdbyCampaignId.get((Id)so.get('Id')) == ''){
            lstMemberStatus.addAll(getListMemberStatusMarketing(so.Id));
        }
        if (recordTypeIdbyCampaignId.get((Id)so.get('Id')) == ''){
            lstMemberStatus.addAll(getListMemberStatusEmail(so.Id));
        }
    }
        


    public static List<CampaignMemberStatus> getListMemberStatusMarketing (Id campagneId){

        List<AM_Statut_de_campagne_marketing__mdt> mcs = AM_Statut_de_campagne_marketing__mdt.getAll().values();
        List<CampaignMemberStatus> cms = new list<CampaignMemberStatus>();
        
        for (AM_Statut_de_campagne_marketing__mdt mc : mcs){
            CampaignMemberStatus ms = new CampaignMemberStatus();
            ms.CampaignId = campagneId;
            ms.Label = mc.label;
            ms.SortOrder = (Integer)mc.AM_SortOrder__c;
            cms.add(ms); 
        }
        return cms;
    }


    public static List<CampaignMemberStatus> getListMemberStatusEmail (Id campagneId) {
        
        List<AM_Statut_de_campagne_email__mdt> mcs = AM_Statut_de_campagne_email__mdt.getAll().values();
        List<CampaignMemberStatus> cms = new list<CampaignMemberStatus>();
        
        for (AM_Statut_de_campagne_email__mdt mc : mcs){
            CampaignMemberStatus ms = new CampaignMemberStatus();
            ms.CampaignId = campagneId;
            ms.Label = mc.Label;
            ms.SortOrder = (Integer)mc.AM_SortOrder__c;
            cms.add(ms); 
        }
        return cms;
    }
}
```

AM_TRGHDL_Campaign_Member_Status_TEST

```
@isTest
public with sharing class AM_TRGHDL_Campaign_Member_Status_TEST {
    private static String TU_PREFIX = 'TRGHDL_Campaign_Member_Status';


    @TestSetup
    static void makeCampaign() {

        id recordTypeMarketing = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('AM_Campagnes_evenements_marketing').getRecordTypeId();
        id recordTypeEmail = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('AM_Campagne_mass_email').getRecordTypeId();

        Campaign testcampagne1 = AM_DataFactory_TEST.genCampaign(TU_PREFIX + 'testcampagne1', null);
        testcampagne1.RecordTypeId = recordTypeMarketing;
        Campaign testcampagne2 = AM_DataFactory_TEST.genCampaign(TU_PREFIX + 'testcampagne2', null);
        testcampagne2.RecordTypeId = recordTypeEmail;

        insert new List <Campaign> {testcampagne1, testcampagne2};



    }

    @isTest
    static void TEST_TRGHDL_Campaign_Member_Status_Marketing (){

        Campaign testcampagne1 = [SELECT Name, Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name =:TU_PREFIX + 'testcampagne1'];
        List <CampaignMemberStatus> lstMemberStatus = new List<CampaignMemberStatus>();
        List <Campaign> lstCampaign = new List <Campaign> ();

        Campaign testCampaign = new Campaign();

        testCampaign.Name = 'nouveau';
        insert testCampaign;
        lstCampaign.add(testCampaign);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include more detail about "it doesn't work".  Are you getting error messages?  What do you expect to get and what are you getting instead?  Please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Metadata Type records (i.e. records for objects that end in `__mdt`) are metadata, and thus you have access to whatever records you have for that Custom Metadata Type *in the org that you're executing the test in*.

If you're trying to deploy this to a new org, then you'll also need to deploy the Custom Metadata Type *and its records*. `__mdt` records, being *metadata*, can't be inserted (or rather, deployed) in a test, so you need to ensure that there is at least one `__mdt` record in the org where you're executing this test.

The alternative to this is to make and use a proxy class to act as, well, a proxy between the code that wants to use the Custom Metadata Type, and the Custom Metadata Type itself. Adding that layer of abstraction would allow you to create an *in-memory* instance of your `__mdt` record in your test, and to have it used in the code being tested.

A template for such a proxy class would be

```java
public with sharing class MyMetadataProxy{
    private static List<My_Metadata__mdt> metadata = new List<My_Metadata__mdt>();
    private static Boolean useProvidedData = false;

    // This method is what allows us to craft in-memory instances in tests
    public static void setMetadata(List<My_Metadata__mdt> providedData){
        if(providedData != null){
            metadata = providedData;
        }

        useProvidedData = true;
    }

    public static List<My_Metadata__mdt> getAll(){
        // The purpose of this IF is to make the proxy "transparent" to its
        //   clients.
        // Fetches (and caches on the heap) the actual metadata type records
        //   in an org if we haven't previously called setMetadata() in this
        //   transaction.
        if(metadata.isEmpty() && !useProvidedData){
            metadata = My_Metadata__mdt.getAll().values();
            useProvidedData = true;
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

You'd use in in your code like so

```java
List<AM_Statut_de_campagne_marketing__mdt> mcs = MyMetadataProxy.getAll();
```

And you'd create an in-memory test metadata record like so

```java
MyMetadataProxy.setMetadata(new List<My_Metadata__mdt>{
    new My_Metadata__mdt(field1__c = 'value 1', field2__c = 'value2')
};
```

Yes, the `getAll()` method returning a List instead of a Map breaks the expectation of the metadata type "interface", but names are easy enough to change if that's an issue for you.

Comment: the Proxy solution is the way to go because it allows for test isolation. Relying on org CMDT is a recipe for failed tests at unexpected times.