I can insert but not update custom metadata
I am just updating the time in formula (long text field) for the test
{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Approval_Criteria__mdt"
  },
  "DeveloperName" : "Test_Metadata",
  "MasterLabel" : "Test Metadata",
  "Formula__c" : "2024-08-21 17:59:37"
}

This is then going in a callout and back and going into
public class CustomMetadataHelper {
    public static String upsertMetadata(List<sObject> customMetadataList) {
        //Create Deployment container for custom Metadata
        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
        for (sobject sObMD : customMetadataList) {
            //Get metadata object name and details
            String sObjectname = sObMD.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

            //Create custom Metadata instance
            Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata = new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
            customMetadata.protected_x = false;
            String recordName = String.valueOf(sObMD.get('DeveloperName')).replaceAll(' ', '_');
            customMetadata.fullName = sObjectname + '.' + recordName;
            customMetadata.label = (String) sObMD.get('MasterLabel');

            //Get all fields
            schema.SObjectType sobjType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectname);

            Map<String, Schema.sObjectField> sObjectFields = sobjType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            Set<String> skipFieldSet = new Set<String>{ 'developername', 'masterlabel', 'language', 'namespaceprefix', 'label', 'qualifiedapiname', 'id' };

            // Use getPopulatedFieldsAsMap to get the populate field and iterate over them
            for (String fieldName : sObMD.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().keySet()) {
                system.debug(skipFieldSet.contains(fieldName.toLowerCase()));
                if (skipFieldSet.contains(fieldName.toLowerCase()) || sObMD.get(fieldName) == null)
                    continue;

                Object value = sObMD.get(fieldName);
                //create field instance and populate it with field API name and value
                Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
                customField.field = fieldName;

                Schema.DisplayType valueType = sObjectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();
                if (value instanceof String && valueType != Schema.DisplayType.String) {
                    String svalue = (String) value;
                    if (valueType == Schema.DisplayType.Date)
                        customField.value = Date.valueOf(svalue);
                    else if (valueType == Schema.DisplayType.DateTime) {
                        //DateTime is a special case which we need to handle carefully. It is working in my case you need to handle it.
                        try {
                            String d1 = svalue;
                            list<String> d2 = d1.split('-');
                            list<integer> timeComponent = new List<integer>();
                            timeComponent.add(Integer.valueOf(d2[0]));
                            timeComponent.add(Integer.valueOf(d2[1]));
                            timeComponent.add(Integer.valueOf(d2[2].left(2)));

                            String t = d2[2].substringBetween('T', '.');

                            list<String> time1 = t.split(':');
                            timeComponent.add(Integer.valueOf(time1[0]));
                            timeComponent.add(Integer.valueOf(time1[1]));
                            timeComponent.add(Integer.valueOf(time1[2]));

                            Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstance(
                                timeComponent[0],
                                timeComponent[1],
                                timeComponent[2],
                                timeComponent[3],
                                timeComponent[4],
                                timeComponent[5]
                            );
                            customField.value = dt;
                        } catch (exception ex) {
                        }
                    } else if (valueType == Schema.DisplayType.Percent || valueType == Schema.DisplayType.Currency)
                        customField.value = Decimal.valueOf(svalue);
                    else if (valueType == Schema.DisplayType.Double)
                        customField.value = Double.valueOf(svalue);
                    else if (valueType == Schema.DisplayType.Integer)
                        customField.value = Integer.valueOf(svalue);
                    else if (valueType == Schema.DisplayType.Base64)
                        customField.value = Blob.valueOf(svalue);
                    else
                        customField.value = svalue;
                } else
                    customField.value = value;
                //Add fields in the object, similar to creating sObject instance
                customMetadata.values.add(customField);
            }
            //Add metadata in container
            mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
        }

        //debug records
        System.debug('customMetadataRecords: ' + JSON.serializePretty(mdContainer));

        // Callback class instance
        CustomMetadataCallback callback = new CustomMetadataCallback();

        // Enqueue custom metadata deployment
        // jobId is the deployment ID
        Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
        return jobId;
    }
}

the debug at custom metadatarecords reads as
{
  "components" : [ {
    "fullName" : "Approval_Criteria__mdt.Test_Metadata",
    "values" : [ {
      "value" : "2024-08-21 17:59:37",
      "field" : "Formula__c"
    } ],
    "protected_x" : false,
    "label" : "Test Metadata",
    "description" : null
  } ]
}

it works for inserts but for updates it just errors out and gives me a An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 61079-384904 (1418567886) which is less than helpful
EDIT:
this is editing our own metadata so no packaged issues and I have given the user full admin modify all permissions to rule that out

...or you can accomplish the same outcome using the correct approach - abstraction of capability and mocking. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/403896/how-to-mock-inject-or-otherwise-make-custom-metadata-available-to-apex-tests

this isn't for tests this is so I can insert updates from a ui component

I identified the issue: the necessary permissions were incomplete. Both 'Customize Application' and 'Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions' are required, but I had only assigned the 'Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions' permission.
